# Twilio could not find a Channel with the specified From address

Tags: c#, .net, twilio

I'm trying to configure a twilio whatsapp messenger in my API, when using the sandbox number, it works perfectly, but when I changed to my 'Twilio phone number' (It's a Brazilian number), I started to recive "Twilio could not find a Channel with the specified From address" I'm certain that the number the API is trying to use matches the Twilio phone number, so it can't be that. Does anyone knows what could be my problem?

```
TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
var messageOptions = new CreateMessageOptions(
new PhoneNumber("whatsapp:" + "+55" + beneficiary.Telephone));
messageOptions.From = new PhoneNumber(sender);
messageOptions.Body = message;
var messageResponse = await MessageResource.CreateAsync(messageOptions);
```

this "sender" is the twilio phone number that i Have configured in twilio console

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp sender don't include the plus sign. Try dropping it and use something like this

```cs
new PhoneNumber("whatsapp:" + "55" + beneficiary.Telephone));
```

Comment: I'm still having the same problem

Comment: Can you try it with a different, non-sandbox WA number from another country?